# Odds of rolling a 1,2,3,4,5,6 in 10 rolls - die probability

Tags: probability

What are the odds of rolling a 1,2,3,4,5, and 6 in 10 rolls on a standard 6 sided die?

The main thing that I am getting caught up on is calculating duplicates.  For example, the first roll you will know that the number you will not have rolled before.  After that, each time you roll, there is the possibility that the number is a duplicate.

Comment: This is an inclusion-exclusion problem. You need to consider the odds that your rolls are all contained in $S$ where $S$ is any subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Then apply inclusion-exclusion to those numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Thomas.  Could you do a quick example of inclusion-exclusion (maybe with my question)?

Comment: Please edit to include the question in the body, not just in the title.

Comment: Probably hard to give a quick example in comments, if you haven't covered it.

Comment: Thomas - I understand the basics.  The example we went over was with overlapping circles.  The problem I am having is how to apply this to probabilities (this is a 100 level course)